# Transition in Slideshow not working

Tags: javascript

Today I managed to create a slideshow in javascript that has a fancy transparent transition, however, my problem is that after it reproduces the first 2 images, the next ones won't appear, and the slideshow repeats the second picture over and over again.

I've tried a few methods that did not work at all.

Any help and insight to the problem will be very important to me!
Here is a link to my code: [eBRabp](http://codepen.io/wristcutter69/pen/eBRabp/) 

My Javascript code:

```
// JavaScript Document
var myImage = document.getElementById('mySlide');

var imageArray = ["images/slider1.jpg","images/slider2.jpg","images/slider3.jpg","images/slider4.jpg","images/slider5.jpg","images/slider6.jpg","images/slider7.jpg"];

var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage() {

  mySlide.className = 'hiding';

  setTimeout(function() {
    mySlide.setAttribute('src', 'images/slider2.jpg','images/slider3.jpg','images/slider4.jpg','images/slider5.jpg','images/slider6.jpg','images/slider7.jpg' + imageArray[imageIndex] + '.jpg');
    mySlide.className = 'showing';
  }, 1000);

  imageIndex++;

  if (imageIndex == imageArray.length) imageIndex = 0;
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage, 3000);
```

Comment: You should include some code in your question ... see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in: mySlide.setAttribute... line... It will not work, of course, because you have placed too much (wrong) arguments. You need just two, and since you have array of images set, simple, do this:

```
mySlide.setAttribute('src',  imageArray[imageIndex]);
```

And it should work:
https://jsfiddle.net/9pd4hnyn/